# Multithreading and closures in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, closures

If I have this:

```
public string DoSomething(string arg)
{
    string someVar = arg;
    DoStuffThatMightTakeAWhile();
    return SomeControl.Invoke(new Func<string>(() => someVar));
}
```

And this method can be called concurrently from multiple threads, and one thread is stuck at `DoStuffThatMightTakeAWhile`, and then a second thread calls `DoSomething` with a different `arg`, will this change the value of `someVar` for all threads and consequently, `DoSomething` return the second version of `someArg` on both calls, or will one `someVar` exist for each thread?

**Edit** I think my `Action` should have been a `Func` so edited it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a number of confusions in the answers here, mostly based upon the untruth that local variables are allocated "on the stack of the thread". This is both false and irrelevant.

It's false because the local variable may be allocated on some temporary pool or the long-term storage pool; even if it is allocated on a temporary pool, that need not be stack memory; it could be a register. It's irrelevant because who cares what pool the storage is allocated on?

The relevant fact is that **a top-level local variable is allocated per method activation.** More generally, a local variable in a block is allocated once per the block being entered; a local variable declared in the body of a loop, for example, is allocated every time the loop goes around.

So, let's consider your question:

> This method can be called concurrently from multiple threads. If one thread is stuck at DoStuffThatMightTakeAWhile, and then a second thread calls DoSomething with a different arg, will this change the value of someVar for all threads?

No. There is a new "someVar" for *each activation* of DoSomething.

> will one someVar exist for each thread?

One "someVar" will exist for each *activation*. If a thread does exactly one activation then there will be exactly one someVar per thread; if a thread does a million activations then there will be a million of them.

That said, Jon Hanna's answer is also correct: if you make a delegate which both reads and writes a local variable, and you hand *that delegate* out to multiple threads, then all the activations *of the delegate* share the same local variable. There is no magical thread safety created for you; if you want to do that then you are responsible for ensuring thread safety.

Comment: So in a few words, a declaration like `string myVar;` will __create__ a new `myVar` pretty much like I'd creating an object with the `new` keyword? Would this also apply to recursive calls (if `DoSomething` would call `DoSomething`)?

Comment: @jsoldi: The way the memory allocator creates new locals and the way it creates new storage for objects can be very different behind the scenes, but conceptually they are the same thing. And yes, recursive calls are *activations* just like non-recursive calls. Every *activation* gets a new batch of locals.

Comment: Why you are calling this a "method activation" and not a "method call". Is this a special term?

Answer (score 7):

Local variables stored in the current thread's stack, so each thread will have its own stack and each own `someVar` variable in it.

Since it would be different values in each thread

```
new Action(() => someVar));
```

will capture it's own value of `someVar`.

**Edit**

I was simply wrong saying that, as Eric pointed. See his answer for correct explanation.

Comment: Saying "local variables are stored on the current thread's stack" isn't correct. Any variable that is captured in a closure is allocated on the heap.

Comment: Jason is correct. This answer does not have sound logic in it.

Comment: Yep, my bad, I won't modify my answer, cos your one is just perfectly good.

Answer (score 1):

As said, each thread hitting `DoSomething` is creating a separate `someVar` on its stack, and therefore no thread has any effect on another's `someVar`.

It is worth noting though, that if a local is captured in a closure and there is multi-threading initiated in that scope, that this can indeed cause different threads to affect the values each other sees, even in the case of value types (which we would normally think of as not something that another method can affect - in this way closures are not like class methods:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 0;
    new Thread(() => {while(x != 100){Console.WriteLine(x);}}).Start();
    for(int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
    {
        x = i;
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
    x = 100;
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Demonstrates this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in your example there is only one `x` (the one created in the main thread) that is being accessed by every thread?

Comment: Exactly, the thread manually created keeps writing it to the console, while the main thread increments it.

Comment: Note that someVar is not allocated on the stack in the first place. Closed-over locals are allocated on the heap because their lifetimes are extended.

Comment: Yep. @EricLippert succinctly says something that wasn't quite coming out right when I posted. Indeed, my first sentence incorrectly says the opposite, though since the lifetime isn't extended in that case it's logically the same as far as multithreading goes, my point being that sometimes the only-one-thread-can-see this reasoning that applies to locals still applies, and sometimes it doesn't.