# Multiple threads getting same value (value type), but threads are not created until after value changes

Tags: c#, multithreading

**BackGround**

I have created a simple program which "races" threads. This is not complete, but it's a test bed for learning new things.

Right now, I'm at the "learning how to create threads" stage.

The program looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10, i++)
        {
            Thread racer = new Thread(() => GetRacer(i));
            racer.Start();
        {

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static Racer GetRacer(int designation)
    {
        return new Racer(Convert.ToString(designation));
    }

}

public class Racer
{
    public Racer(string name)
    {
        Random myRand = new Random(1234);
        Thread.Sleep(myRand.Next(1000, 2000));
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
{
```

---

**Problem**

The specific problem that I am having is that multiple Racers have the same name, but the value of `i` changes before the new Racer is created. Why is this so?

Comment: Because of race condition. You don’t have a closure so the thread gets the value the variable has at that point and the thread can start whenever. It’s not synchronous or instantaneous.

Comment: That's exactly the thing that confuses me. The thread is not created until after the variable has changed value, so I don't see how two threads would ever get the same value of i.

I understand that once the threads are created there is a race condition. What I'm not understanding is how multiple threads are being created before the value of i changes.

What's worse, I don't understand how sometimes threads get a name "10" when i will never be 10.

Comment: Because there can be many threads that are created at the same time, before the variable changes again. There surely aren’t many with number 1 but there may be many with number 5 for example, if that’s when they happen to be created.

Comment: It comes down to how the compiler implements the instruction. In this case, the value of i is only retrieved when the function is called by the new thread not when the thread is created. So if several spawned threads call the function in between loop iterations of the spawning thread, they will get the same value. Avoid this by using ParameterizedThreadStart.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/

Comment: @HansPassant quick question, isnt this fixed in the new version of .net by default?

Comment: As noted by Eric, they changed the behavior for `foreach` but not for `for`.  There is a good reason for that, perf of the loop will be drastically worse when the loop variable has to be stored in a field.  Why they cannot generate a compile warning is the bigger question.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen That's exactly what was happening, I just didn't see it until I looked at the IL.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in comment from @Sami, you can solve it by using another local variable.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int copy = i;
            Thread racer = new Thread(() => GetRacer(copy));
            racer.Start();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static Racer GetRacer(int designation)
    {
        return new Racer(Convert.ToString(designation));
    }
}

public class Racer
{
    public Racer(string name)
    {
        Random myRand = new Random(1234);
        Thread.Sleep(myRand.Next(1000, 2000));
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

More explanations can be found in similar post. [Multithreading and closures in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570152/multithreading-and-closures-in-net)

Comment: At my fathers urging I looked at the IL in DotPeek. After a while of examining it, I figured out why the problem was occurring. When you create a lambda, the compiler creates a class which contains as fields all inputs to the lambda, and then a method which is the lambda. What was happening was that a single instance of this class existed, and as such, it's field i was updated everytime the for loop changed it's i. The reference to this objects method was then pushed onto the evaluation stack for Racer. So what happened was that when Racer finally got time, it used whatever the newest i was.

Comment: Now I just need to know if I should write this up as an answer for future askers.

Answer (score 1):

After inspecting the IL (which was my first time doing so, I'll admit), I found that the problem lies in the way in which Lambdas are implemented. As a disclaimer, I don't fully understand what's happening here, but I think I understand enough to know what the issue is.

---

If we look at the IL, we can see that the compiler creates a new object called `<>c__displayclass0_0`. This class is the way that the lambda is implemented.

It creates a field `.field public int32 i`, which corresponds to the input of the lambda, and a method which corresponds to the lambda itself.

The `Main` method only has one instance of the `<>c__displayclass0_0`. Whenever the for loop changes the value of `i`, it also updates the value of `<>c__displayclass0_0.field public int32 i`.

It then creates and starts the new thread, passing it a reference to the one instance of `<>c__displayclass0_0`. Then, because that iteration of the for loop is complete, it starts the for loop again. As such, if the value of `<>c__displayclass0_0.field public int32 i` happens to change before the new thread gets execution time, then the new value of `i` will be used.

This has the interesting side effect that sometimes a thread will display the value 10, because the for loop increments i before checking to see if it's below 10.